# Comments for more entities

Tags: java, design-patterns, comments

I'm thinking for a time to add a comments functionality to my app. My problem is that I want the comments to be enabled for more "entities" like pictures, locations, users and more.

The naive solution I'm thinking about is to add a a foreign key to the Comment table for each of these entities. So, a foreign key to the Picture table, one for Location table and so on.

Anyway, it doesn't seem to be a good pattern. Because I think this functionality is common to many applications/websites, I thought that maybe some of you saw a nice pattern in his/her experience and can share the idea.

Thanks.

Comment: Actually the foreign key would go to the comments table.
Picture{
  private Comment comment;
}
So its Picture->Comment instead of Comment->Picture

Comment: Dude, I think it can be understand really clear what I have ment. Beside gramatical/language analysis, are you able to give an answer, or this is all you can do?
English is not my native language.

P.S. You are really smart that you know english. There are so few people in this world that knows it.

Comment: I was saying that the relation would go the other way around, as in, the comments table would not have any foreign keys, the other tables would have a foreign key to the comments table.